# Dynamic input field not taking its value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a button on click. I am creating HTML table rows in `tbody`, as my `thead` and `body` are in different different components I am using `ref` to get the fields of `tbody` component.

The issue is I am trying to print my table data to printer and on click it is not taking the values inside that.

**Code**

```
 print() {
  const inputs = this.$refs.tablebody.getElementsByTagName("input"); // by this getting input fields
  for (let input of inputs) {
    input.placeholder = input.value;
  }
  this.$htmlToPaper("printMe");
  for (let input of inputs) {
    input.placeholder = "";
  }
}
```

In the above it throws error as input is undefined as refs is not giving value

This is the error I am getting:

`Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs.tablebody.getElementsByTagName is not a function"`

Here is [my code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-cori-jl92i).

The main issue is on click of print it is printing blank rows not taking values of input fields. Is there any other approach which is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `v-for`, you cannot use ref in v-for, as it may have multiple elements, then Vue simply do not know exactly which component you are referring.

There are two solutions to solve it.

**First Approach**: change template.

from

```
<HelloWorld ref="tablebody" v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row"></HelloWorld>
```

to

```
<div ref="tablebody">
    <HelloWorld v-for="(row, key) in tableDatas" :key="key" v-bind.sync="row"></HelloWorld>
</div>
```

**Second Approach**: change js only.

Instead of using one ref, I use the same format as you would like.

```js
const tableBodies = this.$refs.tablebody; 
tableBodies.forEach(tablebody => {
    const inputs = tablebody.$el.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (let input of inputs) {
      input.placeholder = input.value;
    }
    this.$htmlToPaper("printMe");
    for (let input of inputs) {
      input.placeholder = "";
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey but that one is destroying my print layout, as it is taking input field also I am removing border on @media print please check

Comment: It should not take border as I am removing them

Comment: I did not look at your styling, as this is another issue, which you should have a look. But in case there are difference between the two, I provide solution two, which you may use, with same template setup as yours, no div to be added. Not sure if the styling will be affected, after all it depends on your styling.

Comment: But on media print it is not taking any styling

Comment: media is using style, as you have placed. Seems like an issue, with your plugin, `vue-html-to-paper` and your code. Please have a check yourself first.

Comment: That is where I have stuck why that is not taking media styles(html-to-paper)